# Bootstrap browser differerence

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a site with wordpress [Roots-theme (Twitter Bootstrap)](http://demo.rootstheme.com/)

However, I'm having some problems with the header. In chrome, firefox, opera, safari the front page looks like this:

[image]

There's also a shade difference between the footer and header, and they should both have #ff7300.

On IE it looks like this

[image]
The header has no orange at all, and I'm wondering why. I'm pretty sure it has a background image or something, but I've had no luck removing it. How I can do this?

Comment: I expect that you have an issue with a transparency in your CSS. However, it is really hard to sort that out without an URL. Do you have a public address that you can post?

Comment: @s_ha_dum http://bit.ly/V00UqZ (The least I want know is google punishing me with penguin or indexing of pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `filter:...` in bootstrap.css for the `.navbar-inner` rule. That only runs in IE and it responsible for changing that Orange at the top to the light gray you see only in IE.

I can see the color difference but I can't isolate it. Weird.

Comment: It is purely aesthetic. If you like the look better without it, then remove it or comment it if you are worried that you might want to reverse the edit.

Comment: http://bit.ly/TrdUo8 take a look at the bootstrap.css... how I'm supposed to find it there? I've unpacked it once and it broke the layout so...

Comment: Ouch. Search for `.navbar-inner`. It is about 3/5 of the way through the file. I'd recommend always keeping a development and a minimized copy of these.

Comment: actually I just did .navbar-inner{filter:none} in app.css :)